# Jquery nestedSortable: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

This is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/107bx70o/3/

```
var ns = $('ol.sortable').nestedSortable({
    forcePlaceholderSize: true,
    handle: 'div',
    helper: 'clone',
    items: 'li',
    opacity: .6,
    placeholder: 'placeholder',
    revert: 250,
    tabSize: 25,
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    toleranceElement: '> div',
    maxLevels: 3,
    isTree: true,
    expandOnHover: 700,
    startCollapsed: false,
    change: function() {
        console.log('change');
    },
    sort: function() {
        console.log('sort');
    },
    relocate: function() {
        console.log('relocate');
    }
});

$('#toArray').click(function(e) {
    arraied = $('ol.sortable').nestedSortable('toArray', {startDepthCount: 0});
})
```

When the button is clicked, you get the error.

I did try also last version on github: https://github.com/ilikenwf/nestedSortable

But error is the same. My code is exactly as the Fiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just missed to set `ids` to the `li` `menu` ,

```
<li id="menuItem_1"> ....</li>
```

Here is a workin [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bRIMOs/107bx70o/4/)